How get T when JsonSerializer.Deserialize into generic class?
The the following json was deserialized:
{
    "RESPONSE": {
        "MASDAT": [],
        "TEXTS": [
            {
                "COMPANY": "",
                "PLANT": "0001",
                "PLANTX": "Werk 0001"
            }
}

}
Into following class. Where T is any object wit data.
public class FMPResponseDto<T>
{
    [JsonPropertyName("RESPONSE")]
    public required T Response { get; set; }
}

Desserialization looks like:
var data = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<FMPResponseDto<T>>(responseBody);
retrun data

How can I get only T after deserialization and before datas return from my method?
For example I have some dto:
public class FMPFactoryResultDTO
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("TEXTS")]
        public required FMPFactoryItemDto[] Factories { get; init; }

        [JsonPropertyName("STATUS")]
        public int Status { get; init; }

        [JsonPropertyName("MESSAGE")]
        public string? Message { get; init; }
    }

Desserialization looks like:
JsonSerializer.Deserialize<FMPResponseDto<FMPFactoryResultDTO>>(responseBody);

Also i have a lot of methods that wait only instanse of the FMPFactoryResultDTO. Can i do this without:
new FMPFactoryResultDTO {
Factories = data.Response.Factories,
....
....
}

data.Response? Or what is the question? What do you mean by "get only T"?

Guru Strom Please look, I clarified the question.

Still not  clear what you are trying to do. Do you need to infer the type of the deserialized data or is this about extracting the data itself?

Still not clear enough what the problem is. Why are you creating a new FMPFactoryResultDTO instead of simply using data.Response ?
